# React chat app "Cannot read property 'key' of null"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React based chat app. At first the app ran perfectly fine and as I was styling it I got an error coming out of my Messagelist.js component. I've been doing research but can't find any answers into how to fix this bug. Hopefully someone can help me

I've updated React and ran npm audit to see if I downloaded anything corrupt. Also updated libraries. Reviewed my code as well for any syntax errors and couldn't find any

Ive also gone onto previous branches to double check my work and now get this error on them as well

Below is the code for my MessageList.js component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


class Messages extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            allMessages: [],
            displayedMessages: [],
            newMessageText: ''
        }
        this.messagesRef = this.props.firebase.database().ref('messages')
    }

componentDidMount() {
        this.messagesRef.on('child_added', snapshot  => {
        const message = snapshot.val();
        message.key = snapshot.key;
        this.setState({ allMessages: this.state.allMessages.concat( message ) }, () => {
            this.showMessages( this.props.activeRoom )
        });
    });
    this.messagesRef.on('child_removed', snapshot  => {
        this.setState({ allMessages: this.state.allMessages.filter( message => message.key !== snapshot.key )  }, () => {
            this.showMessages( this.props.activeRoom )
        });
    });
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.showMessages( nextProps.activeRoom );
    }

createMessage(newMessageText) {
    this.messagesRef.push({
            username: this.props.user ? this.props.user.displayName : 'Guest',
            content: newMessageText,
            sentAt: this.props.firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            roomId: this.props.activeRoom.key,
        });
    this.setState({ newMessageText: '' });
}


handleChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({newMessageText: e.target.value });
    }

removeMessage(activeRoom) {
    this.messagesRef.child(activeRoom.key).remove();
}

showMessages(activeRoom) {
        this.setState({ displayedMessages: this.state.allMessages.filter( message => message.roomId === activeRoom.key ) });
    }

render() {
    return (
        <main id="messages-component">
            <h2 className="room-name">{ this.props.activeRoom ? this.props.activeRoom.name : '' }</h2>
            <ul id="message-list">
                {this.state.displayedMessages.map( message => 
                    <li className="message-info" key={message.key}>
            <div className="username">
                { message.username }
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                { message.content }
            </div>
            <Moment element="span" format="MM/DD/YY hh:mm A" className="sent-at">
                { message.sentAt }
            </Moment>
            <Button type="button" className="btn-remove-msg" onClick={() => this.removeMessage(message)} >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon='minus-circle'/>
            </Button>
        </li>
    )}
    </ul>
    <form id="create-message" onSubmit={ (e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.createMessage(this.state.newMessageText) } }>
            <input type="text" value={ this.state.newMessageText } onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) } name="newMessageText" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
        </form>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default Messages;
```

The error from console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null (anonymous function) src/components/MessageList.js:58 55 | } 56 | 57 | showMessages(activeRoom) { > 58 | this.setState({ displayedMessages: this.state.allMessages.filter( message => message.roomId === activeRoom.key ) }); 59 | } 60 | 61 | render() {

Comment: On which line it gives error.

Comment: What is the return value of `snapshot.val()`?

Comment: @MaheerAli line 58

Comment: can you comment the error what you are getting on console screen

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null
(anonymous function)
src/components/MessageList.js:58
  55 | }
  56 | 
  57 | showMessages(activeRoom) {
> 58 |   this.setState({ displayedMessages: this.state.allMessages.filter( message => message.roomId === activeRoom.key ) });
  59 |  }
  60 |     
  61 | render() {

Comment: its weird because when I launch it initially it gives me that error. I can then remove the ".key" from activeRoom and the app will render with no problems then when I add ".key" back to activeRoom it shows messages with no problem.

Comment: Can you log the `snapshot` to console?

Comment: @Nik yes... I believe i found the error in my code. The issue appears to be in to how its being rendered and is fixed... for now. Thank you all for taking the time to help me. Much appreciated

Comment: Glad that you found the solution to your question. If you can put the solution as an answer to this question, it will help others as well. Keep coding. :)